# PEP257 - D212, and D213 conflicts?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use prospector on my docstrings on top of python files.

Here is an example of my docstring:

```
"""item_exporters.py contains Scrapy item exporters.

Once you have scraped your items, you often want to persist or export those items, to use the data in some other
application. That is, after all, the whole purpose of the scraping process.

For this purpose Scrapy provides a collection of Item Exporters for different output formats, such as XML, CSV or JSON.

More Info:
    https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html

"""
```

It has an issue of:

```
pep257: D213 / Multi-line docstring summary should start at the second line
```

Therefore I move the first line down, and it would start at the second line:

```
"""
item_exporters.py contains Scrapy item exporters.

Once you have scraped your items, you often want to persist or export those items, to use the data in some other
application. That is, after all, the whole purpose of the scraping process.

For this purpose Scrapy provides a collection of Item Exporters for different output formats, such as XML, CSV or JSON.

More Info:
    https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html

"""
```

Then if I ran prospector again, I would get D212 as an error.

```
pep257: D212 / Multi-line docstring summary should start at the first line
```

Is there something wrong with D212 and D213?

Comment: Hmm, this seems a bit strange. [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings) says "The summary line may be on the same line as the opening quotes or on the next line." so both would be fine.

Comment: @ChristianDean Is there a way to see if D212 and D213 are added recently? It looks like conflicting rules.

Comment: Ah, I just did a quick google search. This seems releated: https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle/issues/242.

Comment: @ChristianDean Yes it is, somehow I did not find that issue through Google. Thanks a bunch! If you would like, you can post an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Nvm, Zach Beat me to it ;-) Just select his.

Comment: @ChristianDean: I didn't anticipate you checking back. It's a community wiki, though, so good teamwork :-)

Comment: @ZachGates It's cool man. I wouldn't have cared if you posted  it non-community wiki. There just imaginary internet points :P Besides, there will always be more ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> [D212 and D213 are mutually exclusive. You should enable one or none of them. By default, they are both disabled, but if you used the `ignore` flag, you need to also add them.](https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle/issues/242#issuecomment-288166773)

Using the `ignore` flag:

```
--ignore=D212
```

Comment: Prospector doesn't seem to support an '--ignore' argument. My issue and OP is both with prospector. Is there a prospector-specific way to accomplish this without creating a dedicated prospector profile file?

Answer (score 2):

**Root Cause:**

As @zachgates points out in the accepted answer, the problem is two mutually exclusive rules. And while his solution works in other linters, it does not resolve the issue in Prospector, which does not support the `--ignore` flag.

**Solution for Prospector Users:**

For Prospector specifically, there does not seem to be a command-line way to ignore individual rules. The [docs](https://prospector.readthedocs.io/en/master/suppression.html) suggest creating a profile file but this is not portable enough for my use case.

The workaround is to select one of the default profiles from the built-in profiles list [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector/tree/master/prospector/profiles/profiles).

It turns out the profile called `default` is smart enough to not try to catch both mutually exclusive errors. I still can't figure out why prospector *defaults* to a configuration that doesn't have the common sense of it's own built-in profile called `default`.

**Solution:**

This should fix your issue if using Prospector:

`--profile=default`

Comment: Logged as a [bug](https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector/issues/370) and [feature request](https://github.com/PyCQA/prospector/issues/371)